# Memcache bahaviour incase both Web and Memcache servers were installed in same machiene itself

Tags: memcached

I have two servers on which two  web servers and two memcache servers are installed .
I specified Order Of servers for building the  Memcache client  this way

```
String location = "10.1.1.1:11211 10.1.1.2:11211";
    MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(
                AddrUtil.getAddressMap(location), new int[] {1,3});
```

Will this order make any difference in accessing data , if the web and memcache servers were installed in the same machiene itself ??